# What if we call a member function from pointer of derive class which points to base object

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class A
{
    public:
        virtual void Print()
        {
            cout<<"A"<<endl;
            Print(1);
        }
        void Print(int n)
        {
            cout<<"A - "<<n<<endl;
        }
};


class B: public A
{
    public:
        void Print()
        {
            cout<<"B"<<endl;
            Print(1);
        }
        void Print(int n)
        {
            cout<<"B - "<<n<<endl;
        }
};

class C:public B
{
    public:
        void Print()
        {
            cout<<"C"<<endl;
            Print(1);
        }
        void Print(int n)
        {
            cout<<"C - "<<n<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    A *p=new B;
    p->Print();
    ((C*)p)->Print(9);
}
```

Above is my code. The result I got is :

```
B
B - 1
C - 9
```

My question is: why the object `B` can call a function member of class `C` (its child)?  How can object `B` contain code of class `C`?  I just think it will call class `B` member function.  So the result should be:

```
B
B - 1
B - 9
```

Please help me understand what is going on.

Comment: `((C*)p)` is just undefined behavior. You're telling the compiler to override what it thinks it knows about `p`, it's really pointing to a `C`. But it isn't. So, strictly speaking, _any_ output is acceptable. But because `C::Print(int)` doesn't actually rely on any from a `C` instance to achieve its effect, the compiler is able to create the results of "what would happen if `p` really did point to a `C` object".

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, `Print(int)` is not a virtual function, whereas `Print()` is.  So when you explicitly invoke `C::Print(int)` it does not do a lookup of that function in the virtual table.  Instead, it just calls `C::Print(int)`.

The weird thing is that you have cast something to `C` that is *not* a `C` object.  This is undefined behavior.  Indeed, `dynamic_cast<C*>(p)` would return `nullptr`.  What you are doing here is fundamentally incorrect.

You are welcome to call that function without the cast:

```
p->Print(9);
```

But because it's not a virtual function it will output "A - 9", as the type of `p` is `A*`.

If you only want to call that if it's a `C`-derived type, then you can safely do it like this:

```
if (C* pc = dynamic_cast<C*>(p))
    pc->Print(9);
```

Comment: I have tried it with ```dynamic_cast<C*>(p)``` and it still give me the result : ```B
B - 1
C - 9``` , I expected it would be error or weird result, but it doesn't.

Comment: You're misunderstanding.  Do you see how my answer _null-tests_ the dynamic cast?  If you don't do this, and `p` is _not_ derived from `C`, then the dynamic-cast will return `nullptr`.  So what you're describing is the same issue (undefined behavior) because you're essentially doing `((C*)nullptr)->Print(9);` ...  conversely, if you _do_ test it as shown in my example then you won't call the function at all.

Comment: Oh, I have already understood it. Thank you very much @paddy